# Looping through a form to get field names and filed values issue (classic ASP)

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

on submit of a form, I would like to capture the field names and values of the forms and I want them passed without even showing in the browser (Response.Write makes them visible in the browser). How I can do this please? I am using this code:

```
    For Each Item In Request.Form
    fieldName = Item
    fieldValue = Request.Form(Item)

    Response.Write(""& fieldName &" = Request.Form("""& fieldName &""")")       
    Next
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9093918/69820

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your code is essentially correct, so just remove the `Response.Write` and do something else with the `fieldName` and `fieldValue` variables you're populating. After you're done with manipulating the data (either inserting it into a database or sending an e-mail), you can redirect the user to a success / thank you page.

To test that you're receiving the correct input, you can change your `Response.Write` to

```
Response.Write fieldName & " = " & fieldValue & "<br>"
```

**Update**

Here's how you could use a Dictionary Object to put your field names and field values together:

```
Dim Item, fieldName, fieldValue
Dim a, b, c, d

Set d = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each Item In Request.Form
    fieldName = Item
    fieldValue = Request.Form(Item)

    d.Add fieldName, fieldValue
Next

' Rest of the code is for going through the Dictionary
a = d.Keys  ' Field names  '
b = d.Items ' Field values '

For c = 0 To d.Count - 1
    Response.Write a(c) & " = " & b(c)
    Response.Write "<br>"
Next
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. basically I have a form and it submits to a script. This script had the form FieldNames requests hard coded in the script example: PID = (Request.Form("PID") . Now I created the loop in this script to work dynamically and get the fieldNames from the form, and I want them to be written as [fieldName] = Request.Form("[fieldName]") IN THE SCRIPT.  How I can do it please?

Comment: I see; if I understand correctly, you want to _create_ variables based on the field names with the values that were submitted for them. This isn't possible and the best you can do is either creating an array or Dictionary Object with those name/value pairs.

Comment: Which is the easiet please and How I can apply this to the array? Thanks again

Comment: @ReneZammit, This **IS possible**, see my answer here on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076577/looping-through-a-form-to-get-field-names-and-filed-values-issue-classic-asp/72470758#72470758

Answer (score 7):

This is a very small snippet I use to show all form fields POSTED

```
<% 
For x = 1 to Request.Form.Count 
  Response.Write x & ": " _ 
    & Request.Form.Key(x) & "=" & Request.Form.Item(x) & "<BR>" 
Next 
%>
```

Comment: This one is a good and a very simple solution also for the issue of **'For Each Loop'** - if you need to **preserve the order** of the **submitted Name/Value of the request**. Thank you I had this issue once and had to work around with a longer and more complicated solution!

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer, and reply to the second question @ReneZammit asked in [his comment from Jan 31, 2012 at 10:17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076577/looping-through-a-form-to-get-field-names-and-filed-values-issue-classic-asp#comment11396232_9077323), Creating "dynamic" ASP/VBScript variables based on the field names **IS POSSIBLE**!

You just have to use the "magical" `Execute()` function :

```
<%
'If the form was SUBMITTED
If (Request.Form("submitForm") = "1") then

    Dim fieldName
    Dim fieldValue

    'Loop through all the form items
    For Each Item In Request.Form

        'Get Form item properties
        fieldName = Item
        fieldValue = Request.Form(Item)

        'Use Execute() to interpret dynamically created ASP code
        Execute("Dim myVar_" & fieldName)
        Execute("myVar_" & fieldName & " = """ & fieldValue & """")

    Next

    'Use your new Dynamic variables Names, that are now REAL native variables names!
    Response.Write "<br>myVar_banana = " & myVar_banana
    Response.Write "<br>myVar_pear = " & myVar_pear
    Response.Write "<br>myVar_tomato = " & myVar_tomato

'If the form have to be DISPLAYED
else
%>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="banana" value="This is Yellow">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="pear" value="This may be Green">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="tomato" value="This should be Red">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitForm" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<%
end if
%>
```

More information available here : http://www.aspdev.org/asp/asp-eval-execute/