# Requesting field names and values from form and add them on the fly in a script

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

Hi I have a form and the action is submitting into a script named autoform.asp. In this script I usually request the fields values like this: **txtFirstName = Request.Form("txtFirstname")**

Now I want to make this to work dynamically without hard coding the requests in the script where the form is posting.

I managed to do this code to get the the form fields dynamically but they are not being  loaded on the fly.

```
For Each Item In Request.Form
    fieldName = Item
    fieldValue = Request.Form(Item)
    Response.Write(""& fieldName &" = Request.Form("""& fieldName &""")")       
    Next
```

The Response.Write is not good because it is stopping my script to continue. That said the values showing are correct. Can someone help me please? Maybe I need an array? and If yes how I can continue this process? THANKS

Comment: what is the script that is being prevented from running by writing to the browser?

Comment: Basically I want the output to be loaded but NOT shown in the browser. When vbscript is loading the Response.Write, the result is not loading in the background of the sciprt but shown in the browser.....

Comment: so you wish to store the result somewhere? or post it to the next page?

Comment: I need to store the result in the same page where the array is without being displayed in the browser (Response.Write shows the result in browser)

Comment: In other words I dont want to print the field names and values BUT I want to execute them. thanks for your help

Comment: are you saying that if your asp receives an item of data in a request, say `input1=a%20value`, you want a variable in your asp code called `input1` with the value `"a value"`?

Comment: ... a bit like [`import_request_variables`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.import-request-variables.php) in PHP

Comment: @oracle certified professional : YES EXACTLY. please can you tell me how i do it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT as per comment below

You can use the [Execute](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/execute.html) statement to mimic import_request_variables from php

```
For Each Item In Request.Form
   ItemValue = Request.Form(Item)
   Execute Item & " = """ & ItemValue & """"
Next
```

If you are intending to output

Firstname = Request.Form("Firstname")

then use

```
<%
For Each Item In Request.Form
   fieldName = Item
   fieldValue = Request.Form(Item) 
   Response.Write(fieldName & " = Request.Form(""" & fieldName & """)")
Next
%>
```

If you are intending to output

Firstname = "John"

then use

```
<%
For Each Item In Request.Form
  fieldName = Item
  fieldValue = Request.Form(Item) 
  Response.Write(fieldName & " = """ & fieldValue & """")
Next
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I want the results to show in the script only and NOT in the browser and thats my issue. When the script is loading the Response.Write statement, the script is showing the results in the browser and it is stopping there, instead of continuing with the other code in the script. After the fields are loaded, users should be taken to a thank you page :/ As it is, users are being stopped with the values showing in the browser.

Comment: In other words I dont want to print the field names and values BUT I want to execute them. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to work something out using [`Execute()`](http://www.aspdev.org/asp/asp-eval-execute/), eg

```
<%@ language = "VBScript" CodePage = 65001 %>
<%
    option explicit

    dim q
    for each q in Request.QueryString
        dim s
        s = "dim " & q & vbCrLf & _
            q & " = """ & Request.QueryString(q) & """"  & vbCrLf & _
            "Response.Write ""Value of " & q & " is "" & " & q & vbCrLf
        %>
            <pre><%= s %></pre>
            <hr/>
        <%
        Execute s
        %><hr/><%
    next
%>
```

(I've used the querystring collection so it's easier to test). So input like

> http://.../test-asp.asp?p=1&c=328904

will generate something like

> dim p
>   p = "1"
>   Response.Write "Value of p is " & p
>
> ---
>
> Value of p is 1
>
> ---
>
> dim c
>   c = "328904"
>   Response.Write "Value of c is " & c
>
> ---
>
> Value of c is 328904

it depends on what you actually need to do.