# Classic ASP: How to see list of parameters passed from form submission?

Tags: asp-classic

I'm coming from Rails so I'm a little lost since this is my first time touching ASP.

I'm working on a legacy ASP app and I have a form in classic ASP and there are two inputs. How would I view and use the parameters so that I can use them to update my records? Are they stored in some sort of variable by default? And do I do this on the page of the form or the page after?

My input:

```
    <input class="textboxsm" type="text" onkeypress="return numbersonly(window.event.keyCode,1)" onblur="poswarnings(1);updateTotals();" onfocus="rowfocus=0" value="2" maxlength="4" size="2" name="ia1" style="text-align:right;">
```

And this is the button that submits the form:

```
<input width="116" type="image" height="70" onmouseout="this.src='art/order_continue.gif'" onmouseup="this.src='art/order_continue.gif'" onmousedown="this.src='art/down_order_continue.gif'" onclick="return orderdone()" name="submitorder" alt="Done" src="art/order_continue.gif">
```

So how would I extract the value from my input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping through a form to get field names and filed values issue (classic ASP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076577/looping-through-a-form-to-get-field-names-and-filed-values-issue-classic-asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values sent via POST are stored in the `Request.Forms` collection. Items passed via query string are in the `Request.QueryString` collection.

Depending on your setup, you can access the values a number of different ways. Most commonly, people know what form fields to expect, so if you have:

```
<input type="text" name="Title" maxlength="200" size="90" />
```

Assuming your form method is POST, you would retrieve it on the page the form is posted to by:

```
strTitle = Request.Form("Title")
```

This does assume you have already defined `strTitle`, and the value is not null/empty/etc. and/or that you are checking for that later on...

You're pulling the value of the form item named "Title" from the `Request.Form` collection and assigning it to the variable `strTitle` (which should have been defined earlier) From there you can do whatever validation you need to do.

The only thing that would change if you were sending the request via GET instead of POST is you would use the `Request.QueryString` collection - like so:

```
strTitle = Request.QueryString("Title") 'Same assumption as before...
```

Comment: Hey Anon, I updated the question to be more concrete with my HTML inputs.

Comment: @Edmund hopefully that clarifies the principle

Comment: If you use the form `Request("Title")` you'll get the value from the form or the query string without knowing which it came from. This comes in handy in a lot of situations.

Comment: @Craig probably should add something about that, though there's more in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18112650/25163) about the order of the collections checked. I'm not a big fan of blindly accepting from whichever collection first pops a result - too easy for someone to send a value via an unanticipated path. Especially since that will check every collection, and not just the Form/QueryString.